# Copy/Paste Value on multiple excels files

Tags: excel, batch-file

I often have big batches of excels where I have to copy/paste value each sheet, to withdraw formulas and external links.

Those files may have up to 30 sheets, and I receive them by batch of 100... that makes a lot of manual work, opening each excel and copy/paste each sheet in itself.

Do you have any idea about how I could do it quicker? Some code, or some magic trick to help me spare some time?

Thanks a lot for your support! (Please feel free to ask for any more details if needed, I know my english may not be perfect!)

Cheers!

Comment: Do you have an example sheet of input vs. output?

Comment: As Excel has no "command line interface", I see no chance to do it with batch. But it _should_ be possible to do something helpful with Excel macros. You should add the tag "Excel-VBA" to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If all the information is on one tab, you could always just create a copy of that tab and move it to where you want it. Then to get rid of the formulas and external links, once the new tab is created you go to Data - Connections - and Edit Links. There you have to option to break the links.

As for the formulas...the only way i know how to do that would be to highlight then entire page from the top corner, the square between A & 1...and copy and then paste back onto the same page, but Values Only...that will get rid of all of the formulas on the page.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what I was doing, but I have to do it manually for each tab, for hundreds of documents. :(

I was hoping to find a quicker way, some batch process that could avoid me to do it tab by tab, document by document.